# Mumps programming checking for timeout

Tags: programming-languages, error-detection, mumps

I hope you can help me or direct me to someone who can help me.  I am programming in M(UMPS) and I am having  a problem.  In the program I am waiting for a response from the mainframe I do a read (R x:15)  I understand that after 15 seconds if I did not get an answer I will stop waiting for an answer.  I checked my $T and if it there is nothing there or if it is equal to zero I want to stop the program.

This works sometimes, but most often the program will abort prior to checking the $T, I don't even have a chance to see what is in x, how can I catch this before it aborts.  I looked in the console log and everywhere but I do not see any error.  The only error I see is when I look at the unsuccessful task it say err (getr+9    which is the line where I do my read.

```
R x:15   (IT STOPS HERE AND ABORTS if I run out of time)
```

I have tried

```
G:'$T END  
OR
I '$T G END
OR
S TEST=$T
IF TEST=0 ..........
```

But none of these checks happen if I time out.  If I do not time out everything works great.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for StackOverflow. I would recommend moving this question there.

Comment: Which version of MUMPS are you using (be as specific as possible).

Comment: Also, what device are you reading from?  A port?  Have you tried setting an error trap and looking at the error?

Answer (score 2):

By serendipity I ended up on this forum today.
So, maybe this question has been answered already. Anyway, here goes:

The answer to this question is that there can be multiple reasons why no response is received from a remote machine.
When it simply takes too long for the response to be transmitted, the following should work:

Read variable:15 If '$Test Goto ErrorHandler

However, when the communication channel between the two systems gets closed, this is treated as an error condition, so in that case, the following should work:

Set $ETrap="Goto ErrorHandler"

Read variable Set $ETrap="" ; Note that we don't need a time-out to handle this...

Hope this helps